# Can allenes be used as motors or generators?

Tags: allenes

I was thinking about an allene, fucoxanthin:
[image]

Potentially, we can draw a resonance structure in which up to eight of the carbon-carbon double bonds have moved one position to the left, a carbocation is present somewhere along the carbon chain, and the allene is replaced by a carbanion.  We could also imagine beginning with the enol form and one extra C=C bond, in which case the positive charge could be on the epoxy alpha carbon.

It is also conceivable to reverse the polarity, with a carbocation at the allene and a carbanion somewhere on the left.

There *is* a problem, of course, which is that allenes are linear while carbanions are bent. Carbocations should be linear, though I doubt they are as "stiff" as an allene.

To be sure, the bending of these allenes doesn't seem *nearly* as dramatic as [has been observed](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/anie.200705620).  I looked up [the crystal structure](https://www.rcsb.org/3d-view/6A2W) and worked out the bond angle of the allene for 1337, 1383, 1433, and 1481, getting 2.4, 1.6, 0.8, and 0.0 degrees of bending - I doubt any of those are significant differences.  Still, I wonder if the natural world is always so quiet as a crystal structure.

In general... could this molecule interconvert electrical energy to physical force?  Could electrons passing through the photosynthetic complex physically flap the right side of the molecule as they come and go, or could mechanical force on the right side be used to generate "photosynthetic" energy?

Comment: I can't answer your question directly, but this sort of thing seems a bit unlikely. Energy generation in photosynthesis is always by means of H+ ions being pumped against gradient through the cell membrane and then forming ATP as the H+ ions go back via the ATPase enzymes. Most other cases of energy generation or transport in plants or animals happens by some variation of this method.

Comment: I'm quite a few bricks shy of a model there, but fucoxanthin generally is part of an antenna complex that promotes electrons to an excited state.  The energy, if not the electron, manages to make its way to chlorophyll.  Fucoxanthin absorbs energy from low-frequency red light, which is much higher energy than ordinary thermal vibration; it would take some clever mechanism to bring enough force to bear.  (I have no idea).  But first ... can allenes do this *at all*?

Comment: That's an interesting question actually. I don't know about allenes, but there are some molecules (stilbene derivatives) that can flip (cis-trans isomerisation) when light shines on it. There is a lot of research going on about how this can be used as a "molecular switch". There are other systems (such as ferrocene coupled with crown ether + group 1 ion) which can similarly change shape when receiving/losing electron. So it is certainly possible to have systems like this.

Comment: I'm not sure about this particular molecule (=types of molecules), but there has been quite a bit of research on [molecular machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_machine). IIRC excitation-deexcitation mechanisms are also quite popular choices for converting some sort of energy into motion. But no expert here... I've only seen a few talks by Gonzalez about the matter (http://www.columbia.edu/cu/chemistry/groups/gonzalez/).

Comment: I do not answer because the question is somewhat unclear. However, in relation to motion, mechanisms similar to what you described exists. Polyenes and conjugated polymers in general are certainly prone to motion and the mechanism relies on counterions intercalation, chain relaxation it the carbocation, etc. Those can be driven by light, electrochemically, and change might be induced by T or surrounding. Google for artifical muscles, cantilever, etc combined with conjugated polymers.